# How to print all coordinates inside the Contour opencv

Tags: opencv, contour

I am working with image contour detection. I can easily print the contour coordinates but I am interested in printing the coordinates of all the pixels inside the contour. for example if I get a contour of 4 x 4 pixel than i want to print not just the contour but all the coordiantes of the pixels it encloses in opencv

Comment: How to print all the contour pixel would largely depends on how you call `findContours`, so could you plz paste your code for extracting contours?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24252972/193789)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- use findContours to extract the contours of your image. (convert your image to grayscale, apply binary threshold and canny edge detection before, for better results.)

2- select a contour (filter by area, shape, moments etc.)

3- use pointPolygonTest for all points, to check and save if they are inside the specified contour.

Comment: With image of size 2500x2000 I will do 5 millions calls to pointPolygonTest for contours of size 10? I would suggest at least calculating bounding box of contour and then only test points inside this box.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do:
- draw filled contour
- get coordinates of contour and all points inside it
If you are interested only in drawing just use `drawContour` function and set parameter `thickness` to `-1`. It will draw contour and all points inside it.
I'm not sure whether in opencv it's possible to just get all points lying inside some contour - you can write this on your own or just draw filled contour and get all non-black points from image (just use simple loop). It's not very effective solution, but should work fine.

Comment: For completeness note that since thickness=-1 is not particularly self-explanatory, the flag `cv::FILLED` (or `cv2.FILLED` in python) gives more readable code... [drawContours docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way (assuming there is no OpenCV function to do it directly) would be to find the bounding rectangle then raster scan the rectangle keeping track of the winding number (or use pointPolygonTest if efficiency is of no concern).

Answer (score 0):

Contour is a set of points. 
For example in C++ (in java and python everything is similar), contours are stored in vectors:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>>
```

So for example if you are finding contours this way:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours1;
cv::findContours( input_img, contours1, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
```

You can get inside every point of the contour.
This is an example of code that is drawing points of a specific contour.

```
cv::Mat draw = cv::Mat::zeros( 500,500, CV_8UC3 );

int contour_id = 1;

for(int i = 0; i< contour[contour_id].size(); i++)
{
    cout << contour[contour_id][i] << endl; 
    // Now draw every point as a circle with radius = 1

    cv::circle(draw,contour[contour_id][i],1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
}
```

Comment: This is not INSIDE the contour, this only Paints the contour itself, ie the edges.

Comment: it is exactly what I needed though, thank you Tomasz! :)